# Access VBA: Toggle button to filter non-null records

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that uses combo boxes to select certain values from a query. I have a lot of columns that are blank on many records and I was hoping to use a toggle button to filter the query to only return records where a specific column contains info, and if it's not pressed, it will just return all records.

Say for example that I have columns for City, State, Country, I might use combo box to select Canada to return all records in my query that have Canada listed as the country. For those records, if only half of them have a city filled in, can I tie the City column to a toggle button so that when I press it, only the records that contain something in the City column are returned, and if the button is not pressed, it will return all records?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this query helps:

```
SELECT
  city,
  state,
  country
FROM
  some_table
WHERE
  city is not null AND
  city <> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * FROM TBL_WHATEVER WHERE [City] <>"" 

if recordset.eof = true then
    msgbox "No records in recordset",vbokonly
    exit sub
end if

recordset.movefirst

Do while recordset.eof = false
    city = recordset![city]
        if city <>"" then
            with me.combobox1
                .additem recordset![country]
            end with
            recordset.movenext
         end if
loop
```